# can we use copy and paste function in Qwiklab lab

Tags: copy-paste

Can we use copy and paste function in Qwiklab window virtual machine lab in doing coursera course assignment?

I am studying in Google IT Support Certificate and  I find it hard to type the command in powershell lab as the letter in display is too small. I cannot see clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. In the upper left corner, there are three dots. Clicking will open a menu. Look for "Text". If you paste in that editor and click "Send" then it will paste.

Answer (score 0):

The **three dots on the top left corner** is correct for qwiklabs windows VM,
but what about the linux ones?
Google IT Support Coursera modules has many of linux VMs with no option to paste in bash.

Edit: Shift+Insert for Linux VMs

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use `Your Answer` section only when you want to answer the main questions. If you want to comment on any answer, please use `Add a comment` under that answer that you want to comment on. Also, if you need more information, ask for it in the comments section rather than the `Answer` section. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).